# HDMI2VGA raspberry pi 3 RaspAnd boot/config.txt

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, hdmi

Hello I was successful install [RaspAnd](http://raspex.exton.se/?p=453)(tested with a smart tv), I am now trying to use a [hdmi to vga](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00F04N28I) adapter to use a 
noc monitor
[image: noc] and I can not, I checked [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/53457/connect-respberry-3-to-vga-monitor-using-hdmi-to-vga-converter) and [this](https://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/34512708-troubleshooting-a-raspberry-pi-hdmi-vga-adapter) but none work for me, I was try multiple combinations and no thing, here is a "valid"(in my mind) `boot/config.txt` but this not work as others, if some body can help, thanks in advance:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
hdmi_drive=2
config_hdmi_boost=4
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=23
disable_overscan=0
overscan_left=24
overscan_right=24
overscan_top=24
overscan_bottom=24
framebuffer_width=1280
framebuffer_height=720
kernel=zImage
device_tree=bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
dtparam=audio=on
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,cma-256
initramfs ramdisk.img 0x01f00000
mask_gpu_interrupt0=0x400
avoid_warnings=2
gpu_mem=256
enable_uart=1
```

PD: the screen is in black and say "no input signal", with other hdmi source this work ok...